# After signin the data is stored in database but it is not set to current_user. I am new buddy to ruby on rails. I have to implement this in ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After signin the user data is stored in local database but current user is not working.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9tBY.png)

After signin the current user has to be set and the orders_path has to be opened in my case it is redirecting to root path only.The same code is working in ruby 2.6 version but not working 2.4 version. I have to implement this in ruby 2.4. It would be very helpful if someone suggests me where the mistake is.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  
  before_action :ensure_logged_in
  

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end

  def ensure_logged_in
    # ? halt that request cycle
    unless current_user
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  end

  def ensure_owner
    # ? Route to Owners
    unless @current_user.role == "owner"
      redirect_to "/"
    end
  end

  # ? Memoization
  def current_user
    return @current_user if @current_user
    
    current_user_id = session[:current_user_id]
    if current_user_id
      @current_user = User.find(current_user_id)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
  
end
```

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :ensure_logged_in

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      
      session[:current_user_id] = user.id
      session[:current_user_role] = user.role
      flash[:success] = "logged in successfully"
      #@user=user
      
      #UserMailer.with(user: @user).signup_confirmation.deliver_now
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Invalid Login Attemp Please Retry"
      redirect_to new_sessions_path
    end
  end

  # ? Destroying the Session
  def destroy
    session[:current_order_id] = nil
    session[:current_user_id] = nil
    session[:current_user_role] = nil
    @current_user = nil
    redirect_to "/"
  end
end
```

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :ensure_logged_in

  def index
    if current_user
      redirect_to orders_path
    else
      render "index"
    end
  end
 
end
```

```
Home/index.html.erb FILE

<h1 class='logo-name'>
      
      LIBRARY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM
     </h1> 
<div class="links-container">
    
    <div >
    
    <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-20" id="signup" href="users/new"> sign up </a> 
    <a  class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-20" id="login" href="/signin"> login in </a> 
    </div>
   <div id="aboutus">
    </div> 
</div>
```

```
UserCONTROLLER FILE

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
  skip_before_action :ensure_logged_in
  def index 
    
    
  end
  def new
    render "users/new"
  end

  def create
    name = params[:name]
    email = params[:email]
    password = params[:password]
    role = params[:role]
    new_user = User.new(
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password_digest: password,
      role: role,
    )
    new_user.save
    if new_user.save
      
      session[:current_user_id] = new_user.id
      session[:current_user_role] = new_user.role
      #@user=new_user
      flash[:success]="sucessfully signedin"
      redirect_to "/"
    else
      flash[:error] = new_user.errors.full_messages.join(" , ")
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end
  
end
```

```
USER/INDEX.HTML.ERB FILE

<form action="/users" method="post">

    <p class='label'>Name: </p>
   
  <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
    <p class='label'>Role: </p>
    <%= select_tag "role", options_for_select(["student","owner"], "student"), class: "form-field" %>

    <p class='label'>Email: </p>
    <%= email_field_tag :email%>

    <p class='label'>Password:</p>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>

    <%= submit_tag "signup" %>

</form>
```

```
routes.rb file
 get "/" => "home#index"
  get "/signin" => "sessions#new", as: :new_sessions
  post "/signin" => "sessions#create", as: :sessions
  delete "/signout" => "sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_session

 
  resources :orders
  resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check documentation on [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise).

You are basically writing logic to manage authentication yourself which is kind of creating what is already done in the mentioned gem. You could extend it but you are reinventing it.

If you still have to do the logic your side (which I don't recommend) then I suggest to start debugging your code using [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug). Add byebug line just before the calling the current_user in your controller and see why it is not being called. You could follow line by line trying to see even if it is not being called at all.